# FBSDKMessengerSharer shares images but does not give any option to go back to app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiimage, cocoapods

I am using [FBSDKMessengerSharer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/ios) for picture sharing.

The following code works fine but when the sharing is done, it does not show any button to go back to my app.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selfie_pic"];
[FBSDKMessengerSharer shareImage:image withOptions:nil];
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"corgi" ofType:@"webp"];
NSData *webpData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filepath];
[FBSDKMessengerSharer shareAnimatedWebP:webpData withOptions:nil];
```

After getting the picture shared, I want to set the flag so that I can determine if the user has sent on facebook.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this code work properly, make the following changes:

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image = yourUIImage;
photo.userGenerated = YES;
FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
content.photos = @[photo];

[FBSDKMessageDialog showWithContent:content delegate:self];
```

Add Delegate methods

```
#pragma mark === delegate method
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didCompleteWithResults:(NSDictionary *)results{
    NSLog(@"Share Completed:%@", results);
}
- (void)sharer:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
 NSLog(@"Error Occured:%@", error);
}
-(void)sharerDidCancel:(id<FBSDKSharing>)sharer{
    NSLog(@"Sharing Cancelled");
}
```

Up to this step, this code works but in both conditions (share/cancel) it hits sharerDidCancel. To overcome this, your AppDelegte should look like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application{
   [FBSDKAppEvents activateApp];
 }


 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
              annotation:(id)annotation {                         
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
        }


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
 return [ [FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application :application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```